# PowerShell - Replace the third and fourth occurrence of a string

Tags: powershell

I have an xml file that I would like to replace the third and fourth occurrence of a string. I have tried a lot of things but cant get it to work(or even close so I don't think there is any point sharing here). Below I have a sample XML with a similar structure. What I would like is to replace the third and fourth occurrence of book to make it different (eg book2).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

What I would like is to replace the third and fourth occurrence of "book" to make it different like "book2".

I would want the file to have the below when the code runs.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book2>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book2>
</catalog>
```

Then I will run the below code.

```
$filePathToTask = "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Books.xml"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($filePathToTask)
$element =  $xml.SelectSingleNode("/catalog/book2/genre")
$element.InnerText = "Fiction"
$xml.Save($filePathToTask)
```

And finally I will revert the code back to "Book"

Final output would be as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fiction</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

I am very new to PowerShell so I appreciate any help.

Daniel

Comment: I don't think you should do that because that will make it a lot harder for applications to filter out the array of books. If you must, I'd suggest adding an attribute to every `<book>` element. Something like `<book index="1">`,  `<book index="2">` etc.

Comment: i agree with `Theo` that what you are talking about would break the meaning of the XML file. loading your 1st XML into `$Test0`, you can see individual books thus `$Test0.catalog.book[0]`. you can gracefully iterate thru the collection. using your 2nd XML in `$Test2` would not allow such since each `book#` would show as a different _property_ instead of a different collection item.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The reason I am doing this is because the code is developed by a third party and has a known bug that has a workaround downstream. So what I want to do is change the third and fourth occurrence of "book" to "book2", then use  
`$element =  SelectSingleNode("/catalog/book2/genre") 
$element.InnerText = "Fiction"` 
to replace the inner of the genre and then change "book2" back to "book" to return the code back to normal.

Comment: @Daniel - if the file is short, then i would just iterate thru it, count the `<book>` lines, and change the 3rd & 4th when found.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey The file is very short at only 55 lines and will never get bigger. What you have suggested I believe will work but how would the code be structured? Could you give an example?

Comment: @Daniel - are there only the 2 `<book></book>` blocks in each file?

Comment: @Daniel - i went with just two blocks in the Answer i posted. if that is not always true, ten please let me know ... & update your sample data. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like:

```
$filePathToTask = "C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\Books.xml"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($filePathToTask)
$root = $xml.DocumentElement

$books = $root.SelectNodes("/catalog/book")

# Modify the 2nd book genre
$books[1].genre = "Fiction"

$xml.Save($filePathToTask)
```

No need to create intermediate XML.

Answer (score 0):

presuming there are only two `<book></book>` blocks, this seems to do what you want ... [*grin*] i still can't wrap my head around the WHY of it, but that aint important.

what the code does ...

- fakes reading in a file as an array of lines of text
  when you are ready to use real data, comment out the entire `#region/#endregion` block and replace it with a `Get-Content` call.
- sets the target & replacement strings
- sets the "found target" count to zero
- iterates thru the array of lines
- counts the target strings
- once `$TCount` goes above 2, it replaces the target with the replacement string
- sends the current `$Line` to the `$UpdatedInStuff` collection
- displays that on screen

here's the code ...

```
#region >>> fake reading in a file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
'@ -split [System.Environment]::NewLine
#endregion >>> fake reading in a file

$Target = 'book>'
$TReplace = 'book2>'

$TCount = 0
$UpdatedInStuff = foreach ($Line in $InStuff)
    {
    if ($Line -match $Target)
        {
        $TCount ++
        }
    if ($TCount -gt 2)
        {
        $Line = $Line -replace $Target, $TReplace
        }

    $Line
    }

$UpdatedInStuff
```

output ...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book>
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book2>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book2>
</catalog>
```